# Accessing kubeconfig file from Azure artifacts

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-aks, kubeconfig

I am new to Azure DevOps and have a requirement where AKS cluster is provisioned through `terraform` which creates two `kubeconfig admin` & `user files` in Azure Devops artifacts. Now I have to call this kubeconfig files to another pipeline to manage post-provisioning activities of AKS cluster through Ansible playbooks.

Is there any way this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

- One way is to build your terraform with Build yaml pipeline and use the build artifact in a release pipeline, Your build artifact will include the kube config files and then run your ansible task in Release pipeline.
- Another way is to Publish your artifact and Download your published artifact and use it in your ansible task with the YAML pipeline code below:-

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pr: none

stages:
- stage: DeployToAKS
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    environment: 'your-environment-name'  # Optional, if you're using environments
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
            inputs:
              artifactName: 'kubeconfig'
              targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/kubeconfig'

          - script: |
              # Use the kubeconfig files in your Ansible playbooks
              ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml playbook.yml
            displayName: 'Run Ansible Playbooks'
            env:
              KUBECONFIG_ADMIN: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/kubeconfig/admin_kubeconfig
              KUBECONFIG_USER: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/kubeconfig/user_kubeconfig
```

I deployed one AKS with kubeconfig with Azure Devops Release pipeline like below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]

Publish the Artifact and Download the Published Artifact like below and run your Ansible playbook with Ansible playbook Run task:-

[image]